# Asymptotic behaviour of products of Schwartz functions with hyperbolic trig functions

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$ be a Schwartz function, and $\tilde{f}$ be it's Fourier transform - hence still a Schwartz function (we could generalise to the space of $L^2$ functions if needed). Is it true that

$$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \tilde{f}(x)\cosh(x) = 0?$$

It certainly seems that there is at least a subset of functions that satisfies this property - for example $\tilde{f}(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

This seems like it could be possible in general, but I can't seem to formulate a proof. A counter argument is also welcome.

Comment: One small point is that since Fourier transform is a bijection of Schwartz functions to themselves, you don't need to present the question about Fourier transforms of Schwartz functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. First, the Fourier transform is surjective onto the space of Schwartz functions by the inverse formula, so you don't need to take the Fourier transform; it makes no difference.

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function supported on $[0, \infty)$ so that $\phi(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 1.$ Define $f(x) = e^{-x}\phi(x).$ Then $f$ is Schwartz, since $e^{-x}$ is Schwartz for positive reals and $\phi$ cuts off the negative real axis from consideration.

Then $f(x)e^x$ tends to $1$ as $x\rightarrow\infty,$ and so the hyperbolic cosine limit is not zero but $1/2.$